# Subway train route in Newyork city(Penn Station - Battery Park)

Tags: trains, public-transport, new-york-city, train-stations

I want to go to battery park, NewYork from Penn station, Newyork. I searched Google map for direction.

[image: Pennsylvania Station to Battery Park]

I have some doubts about that route.

1. What is the meaning of 1,2 (I circle those in red)

2.It shows 19 min journey. So 19 min journey with 12 stops??? Can any one explain the name of those stops?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Google "NYC subway map" and you will quickly see the 12 stops on the 1 and 2 line from Penn.

Comment: If you click the V-shaped down arrow to the left of the text "16 min (12 stops)," you will see the 12 stops listed with arrival times.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_(New_York_City_Subway_service) and [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/34th_Street–Penn_Station_(IRT_Broadway–Seventh_Avenue_Line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/34th_Street–Penn_Station_(IRT_Broadway–Seventh_Avenue_Line)), especially the pictures that include signs showing a white number 1 in a red circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google is trying to tell you that you can take either the 1 or 2 train to get to South Ferry; just take whichever one comes first. If you tap the "schedule explorer," it will show you both 1 and 2 train routes:

[image: Google Maps schedule explorer showing routes on the 1 and 2 trains]

Now that's odd, because if you look at [the subway map](http://web.mta.info/nyct/maps/subway_map.pdf), you'll see that the 2 train isn't supposed to go to South Ferry at all. It just so happens that some [temporary nighttime maintenance work](http://travel.mtanyct.info/serviceadvisory/routeStatusResult.aspx?tag=2&date=12/27/2018&time=&method=getstatus4) means that the 2 operates as a local and terminates at South Ferry instead of going to Brooklyn. Google Maps knows about the change, so it suggests it as an option. If you change the "Depart At" setting to tomorrow morning, when the maintenance won't be taking place, you'll see that the 2 train is no longer given as an option.

It's a 16 minute ride with 12 intermediate stops. On your phone, if you tap right where it says "16 min (12 stops)," Google Maps will show you the names of the stops you'll be going through. You can also see this on the subway map and inside the subway cars.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have downloaded the map of 1,2 and A . Can you tell me what is the difference between Express downtown and local downtown? It shows the fares are exactly same.

Comment: @Encipher The express train skips certain stops for a faster ride, while the local makes more stops (the 2 running on its modified route at night during these couple of days is not an express train). All rides cost the same fare, regardless of which line you use. As noted in [this guide](https://www.nycbynatives.com/visitors_center/nyc_subway_instructions.php), the map is coded to show which stops are local and which are express, or you can just follow Google Maps.